# How to update a dictionary within firebase while also add a time stamp with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, firebase, angularfire

The following code updates a firebase dictionary within a list and also creates a time stamp for that update, but the complication is that I need to turn the firebase object into an array within the html

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/b84up41y/

This works:

HTML

```
<section ng-app ="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng-repeat= "(id,item) in data">
           <form ng-submit="AddComment(id)">
                <input ng-model="item.comment"></input>
            </form>
</div>

</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
angular.module("myapp", ["firebase"])
    .controller('MyController',function MyController($scope, $firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com");

    $scope.data = $firebase(ref);
    $scope.AddComment = function (id) {
        $scope.data[id].DateLastModified = Date.now();
        $scope.data.$save(id)}


});
```

But when I add |orderByPriority to turn the firebase object into an array so I can apply filter as such

```
<form ng-submit="AddComment(id) |orderByPriority">
```

it no longer works

However, it does work to update the dictionary within the list when I remove the following, which is the component I need.

```
$scope.data[id].DateLastModified = Date.now();
```

According to firebase

> The orderByPriority filter is provided by AngularFire to convert an object returned by $firebase into an array. The objects in the array are ordered by priority (as defined in Firebase). Additionally, each object in the array will have a$id property defined on it, which will correspond to the key name for that object.

However, the id seems to return 0 instead of the id in the example i show

Comment: This is an old version of AngularFire. Consider upgrading. Also, you should be able to replace `(id,item)` with `item` and reference the id using $id on the object, like so: `AddComment(item.$id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `id` of the item directly like so:

```
<div ng-repeat= "item in data|orderByPriority">
           <form ng-submit="AddComment(item.$id)">
                <input ng-model="item.comment"></input>
            </form>
</div>
```

Notice that in `ng-repeat` I am only looking for `item` in `data`. Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KobaKhit/xg9L766x/1/).